# How to do the same as clicking Start, Power, Shut down in Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows, shutdown, win10-fast-startup

By default in Windows 10 and 11 if you click Start, then the power icon then *Shut down* Windows does a "hybrid shutdown" that prepares the computer for a fast start-up. When you next start Windows loads your session from disk so effectively you are just unlocking Windows not logging in.

I want to do this from a command prompt, but I cannot find a way to do it. The help for the `shutdown` command lists an option `/hybrid` so it seems as though:

```
shutdown /s /hybrid
```

should be doing the same as Start, Power, Shutdown but it doesn't. I've tried it several times on my laptop and when powering on the laptop I get the same logon process as after a full shutdown i.e. it takes a (relatively) long time to log on and after logging on my apps have not been restarted.

For clarification: the hybrid shutdown is not the same as *hibernate*. I can hibernate my laptop using `shutdown /h`, but this is not what I want to do. The hybrid shutdown is described [in this answer from Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/difference-between-hybrid-shutdown-and-normal/af888b6c-ac6d-4408-a659-9259bd1e9abe), or Googling it returns a thousand hits.

Some more information:

I put a batch file in my Start menu Startup folder containing the command:

```
time /t >C:\temp\LogonTime.log
```

so whenever I logon to the PC the time I logged on is recorded. Then I did two experiments:

1. I clicked Start, power icon, shut down then turned the laptop back on, waited five minutes and logged on. The time recorded in `C:\temp\LogonTime.log` was the time the laptop restarted not the time I logged on. So Windows had logged me back in when Windows started.
2. As above except I used the command `shutdown /s /hybrid` from a command prompt to do the shutdown. This time the time recorded in `C:\temp\LogonTime.log` was the time I logged in i.e. five minutes after Windows started.

There may be some confusion over terminology as the terms *hybrid shutdown*, *fast start*, etc seem to be bandied around rather loosely, however there is a difference between the two ways of shutting down and my question is how to achieve the same as Start, power, Shut down from the command prompt.

The laptop has a recent install of Windows 11 and I have not messed around with any of the power options, so as far as I know it is still at the default settings.

Comment: shutdown /s /hybrid should work. Are you adding a time /t 0 or /f option maybe?

Comment: @LPChip I have tried both `shutdown /s /hybrid` and `shutdown /s /hybrid /t 0` and they both appear to be doing the same thing i.e. a full shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered how to do this courtesy of Stack Overflow. See [How to do the same as clicking Start, then the power icon, then "Shut down" in Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066891/how-to-do-the-same-as-clicking-start-then-the-power-icon-then-shut-down-in-w) for the details.

The answer is that there is no way to do this without writing your own C program as the `shutdown.exe` command in Windows does not provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The command you entered is slightly wrong.

This should be the correct command to use

```
shutdown.exe /h
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `/h` option is *Hibernate*, which is different from a hybrid shutdown. `shutdown /h` does indeed hibernate my laptop but this is not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the same logon process as after a full shutdown […] and after logging on my apps have not been restarted.

That’s exactly how a shutdown works, no? You seem to be misunderstanding what hybrid shutdown does. You are fully logged out first and then the system hibernates. Your user session is *not* saved and will *not* be restored. This is how Fast Startup has always worked.

What you describe here:

> When you next start Windows loads your session from disk so effectively you are just unlocking Windows not logging in.

…is just regular full hibernation.

Comment: They seem to get shutdown /s when they execute shutdown /s /hybrid.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, it looks as if `shutdown /s /hybrid` is doing the same as `shutdown /s` but I don't understand why since the hybrid shutdown works fine from the Start menu,

Comment: “So there is a difference between full Shutdown and hybrid shutdown.” There isn’t. Windows [sometimes logs you in in the background](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/automatically-finish-setting-up-a-pc-after-an-update-or-restart-a0dadce5-dca1-1c4d-ce14-a0f480f3265e). It is unrelated to hybrid or full shutdown.

Comment: I've added some more info to my question. Perhaps you could try the experiment for yourself. Regardless of what differences, if any, exist between full and fast shutdown there is a reproducible difference between shutting down from the Start menu and from the command line.